# How to change colors in react component

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

In reactstrap we can set colors with default styles(such as primary, secondary, success, warning....) but how do I change it with the Hex color code?
For example, how do I change 'warning' to '#008080'?

```
<AppSwitch
  className={'mx-1'}
  variant={'pill'}
  color={'warning'} //it dones't work with {'#008080'}
  default checked
  onChange={this.handler} />
```

I've also tried something like this but didn't work either:

```
state = {
  color: '#008080'
}


<AppSwitch
  className={'mx-1'}
  variant={'pill'}
  color={'this.state.color'} 
  default checked
  onChange={this.handler} />
```

Comment: should be `color={this.state.color} ` instead of `color={'this.state.color'} `

Comment: have've tried too, didn't work : (

Comment: are you sure that `AppSwitch` is reactstrap component?

Comment: Oh no, it's @coreui/react

Answer (score 3):

You should define it in constants:

```
const hexColor = {
  color: '#008080'
};

<AppSwitch
  className={'mx-1'}
  variant={'pill'}
  color={hexColor[color]} //it dones't work with {'#008080'}
  default checked
  onChange={this.handler} />
```

Comment: It didn't work with "color={ hexColor [color] }" or "color={ hexColor.color }" too

Comment: Create a new file try to export it in your main file: export const hexColor = {
  color: '#008080'
}; in your main file import { hexColor } from './'

Answer (score -1):

If it's okay to change color for all 'warning', you can use [BOOTSTRAP.BUILD](https://bootstrap.build/). You can change color by hex color code in this editor. Export bootstrap.css from it, and refer it in your code instead of bootstrap's default one.